# WordPress Redirect for Non-Logged In

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, buddypress

Ok so I have the code working for redirecting a logged in user to their BuddyPress profile; however, I also need:

**QUESTION HOW TO:**

**Add a redirect for the same page #78 for a non-logged in user to go to:  /login**

```
function buddyforms_redirect_a_page_to_the_buddypress_profile() {
    if( is_page( 78 ) ) {
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            wp_safe_redirect( bp_loggedin_user_domain() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'buddyforms_redirect_a_page_to_the_buddypress_profile' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my example below. I have added the else condition for non-logged in user.

```
function buddyforms_redirect_a_page_to_the_buddypress_profile() {
    if( is_page( 78 ) ) {
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            wp_safe_redirect( bp_loggedin_user_domain() );
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'buddyforms_redirect_a_page_to_the_buddypress_profile' );
```